# try to find middel but program crash linked list in c with two pointers

Tags: c, linked-list

i write function whom Traverse linked list using two pointers. Move one pointer by one and other pointer by two. When the fast pointer reaches end slow pointer will reach middle of the linked list.
but my code crash when i try to move temp pointer by two

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MEM (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node))

void addl(); //add elements at last
void print(); //print linked list
void addf(); //add element at first
void addm(); //add element at middel
struct node {

    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;

void addl()
{
    struct node* new, *temp;
    temp = head;

    new = MEM;

    printf("\n\t\tenter any number : ");
    scanf("%d", &new->data);
    new->next = 0;
    if (temp == 0)
        head = new;
    else {
        while ((temp->next != 0))
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = new;
    }
}
void print()
{
    struct node* temp = head; //
    printf(" \n Elements are : ");
    while (temp != 0) {
        printf(" %d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void addf()
{
    struct node* new;
    new = MEM;
    printf("\n\t\tenter any number : ");
    scanf("%d", &new->data);
    new->next = head;
    head = new;
}
void addm()
{
    struct node* new, *temp, *med;
    temp = head;
    med = head;
    new = MEM; //MEM #define for dynamic memory allocation

    printf("\n\t\tenter m any number : ");
    scanf("%d", &new->data);

    if (temp == 0)
        head = new;
    else {
        while ((temp = temp->next != 0)) {
            med = med->next;
            temp = temp->next; //fist move
            temp = temp->next; //2nd move when i add program crash
        }
        //  new->next=med;
        //med->next=new;
        printf("\n\t\tDATA : %d\n", med->data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    head = 0;
    int i = 5; //create linked list
    while (i) {

        system("cls");
        addf();
        addl();
        i--;
    }
    addm();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

as of now addm not add anything in linked list because code crash while i try to found mid of linked list

Comment: What's `node`? Where's your `main` function? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just a snippet.

Comment: @tolomowe How is this printf("\n\t\tenter m any number : "); related with finding the middle of the list?!

Comment: printf used here just check where crash happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is due to these two line -

```
temp=temp->next;//for one move
temp=temp->next;//for second move when i add this program crash
```

Let's think of two situations -

1) List has one element. Then after the while check condition, dur to `temp=temp->next` line `temp` will point to `NULL`. In next `temp=temp->next` line you are trying to de-reference that `NULL`. That will crash

2) List have 2 elements. After while condition check `temp` will point to last element. And after next `temp=temp->next` line `temp` will point to `NULL`. Now in very next line you are trying to de-reference that `NULL`. Which is another point of crash

You need to remove one `temp=temp->next` from inside loop as it advances `temp` by 3 position in each loop iteration which is clearly a logical bug. Node that after that removing one of them will not eliminate the chance of crash.

Another thing is that the commented code is also wrong.

```
//  new->next=med;
//med->next=new;
```

You may have wanted to do -

```
new->next = med->next;
med->next = new;
```

Comment: i also try    temp=temp->next;
if(temp) temp=temp->next;

Comment: @tolomowe, let's say you have only two nodes, after first iteration of loop `temp` will point to NULL. And in next iteration you are trying to de-reference it without NULL checking. That is also another point where your code could crash. Please check the updated answer